# Аутентификация в Spring Security через SSO

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, безопасность, spring-security

Сейчас стоит задача авторизации пользователя через SSO. Со стороны фронтенда через форму "Login", мотодом POST, будет отправляться строка в теге SESSION_ID из XML для авторизации в формате.

Пример:

```
<SELFCARE>
    <SESSION_ID>eyJraWQ....eyJzdWIi...elEXPFwF...</SESSION_ID>
</SELFCARE>
```

Сами пользователи нигде не хранятся, нужна только авторизация по строке которая пришла из формы.
Не могу понять как настроить конфигурации Spring Security

Comment: Это свой велосипед? Если да, то так просто на ваш вопрос не ответить. Лучше перейти на нормальный OpenID(JWT) или SAML

Comment: Я новичек в этом деле. Так как не знаю всех инструментов, вот и крутятся в голове одни костыли. Задачка выглядит типовой и я понимаю что должен быть способ удобней.  В общем из того что у меня есть, http запрос http://*****/v1/tokens-stub/get?login=user&password=password в котором передаются данные пользователя введённых на форме в ответ приходит session_id с jwt токеном при расшифровке он мне выдает JSON с данными (парсер jwt я написал для получения нужных полей в полях сессия пользователь и т.д)  но как настроить конфигурацию Spring непонятно.

Comment: Слодность ещё в том, что сеть закрытая и пользоваться можно только внутренними ресурсами. То есть этим http://*****/v1/tokens-stub/get?login=user&password=password